# How to make a table with 3 data sets?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been going at this for a while but I'm not quite sure how to tackle it. I have three data sets- **scores** (A-F, counts the number of grades in each rank), **count** (the program prints a table of count by rank), and **Percentage** (dividing the count by the total in the data set to get the percentage in each rank).

The end result should look similar to this given 7 grades (integers). 
(example user inputted data: [88, 76, 89, 78, 74, 87, 95])

```
>>> GRADE  COUNT   PERCENTAGE
>>> A      2       28.6%
>>> B      2       28.6%
>>> C      3       42.9%
>>> D      0       0%
>>> F      0       0%
```

Currently, this is my long, tedious, elementary code. I'm having a hard time with executing and making it work correctly and I probably am not making it work properly at all.

```
def grade_scores(scoreList):
    for score in scoreList: #shows the scores in the score list, uses ddata from previous function
        if score >= 91:
            Ascore = 'A'
            Acount +=1
            sum(Ascore) / Acount len(scoreList) = Apercentage
        elif score >= 81 and score <=90:
            Bscore = 'B'
            Bcount +=1
            sum(Bscore) / Bcount len(scoreList) = Bpercentage
        elif score >= 71 and score <=80:
            Cscore = 'C'
            Ccount +=1
            sum(Cscore) / Ccount len(scoreList) = Cpercentage
        elif score >= 61 and score <=70:
            Dscore = 'D'
            Dcount +=1
            sum(Dscore) / Dcount len(scoreList) = Dpercentage
        else:
            Fscore = 'F'
            Fcount +=1
            sum(Dscore) / Dcount len(scoreList) = Dpercentage
    for i in range(scoreList):
        print ('Grade', '\t', 'Count', '\t', 'Percentage')
        print(Ascore, end="\t", Acount, end="\t", Apercentage)
        print(Bscore, end="\t", Bcount, end="\t", Bpercentage)
        print(Cscore, end="\t", Ccount, end="\t", Cpercentage)
        print(Dscore, end="\t", Dcount, end="\t", Dpercentage)
        print(Fscore, end="\t", Fcount, end="\t", Fpercentage)
```

I would hope to make it more of a grid style instead but I don't think it is formatted correctly and does not seem to work properly ( I also get an error about "len" in the 6th line). I appreciate any input on this.

Comment: Use list for your count, score, and percentage - that will help you a lot

Comment: Thanks! But how may I incorporate lists for the data if it is by a user input? I"ve been trying to use the free "how to think like a computer scientist" book to assist me but so far have not read much about data sets from a user input.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what you meant by the question, but first, the error message is most likely caused by a TypeError, because you are using the variable scoreList in the range() function (which takes in integers, and integers have no length).

Also you may want to consider to utilize **lists** to organize the data better.

For the grid style, you should use the .format() method to help you with printing the lines:

```
# Assuming you have 3 lists:
# grade = ['A','B','C','D','E']
# count = [2, 2, 3, 0, 0] Have another function capture user input
#                          and convert it into this list.
# percentage = [28.6, 28.6, 42.9, 0, 0] Same as above ^

print("SCORE  COUNT  PERCENTAGE")
for i in range(len(grade)):
  print("  {}      {}       {} %".format(grade[i], count[i], percentage[i]))
```

For the elif conditionals, you would have to stick with what you already have. However, you may want to modify the variable names a bit, as a better way to do this is through lists:

```
for i in range(len(gradeInputList)):
  if grade >= 90:
    count[0] += 1  # Increase index 0 (Corresponds to value A) by 1
  elif grade >= 80 and < 90:
    count[1] += 1
    # Omitted code here, you get the idea
    # ...
  else:
    count[4] += 1
```

And at the end you could have another for loop that calculates the average:

```
for i in range(len(count)):
  average[i] = count[i] / sum(count) * 100  # Calculates the percentage
```

Whew, hope this helped! :)

Comment: Not a hard-coded table, the same as shown above. Basically columns for each data set. I know its hard to explain it myself, I have a earlier function (which I should have included) which allows the user to input a data set, and calculates the average, minimum and maximum of the scores.

Comment: @Jennga I have update my answer based upon your response.

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry I don't mean to be be difficult, but what about the el-if loop? Would I still include that information since it is necessary for the ranking? I'm just having so much trouble to understand if what I was doing was correct in the first place with the "Ascore", "Acount", "Apercentage" if that is the correct way to go with this.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Jennga Updated the answer again based off request.

Comment: I don't mean to pester you any further as you have already helped me immensely, but I don't quite understand why I am receiving errors. when the code is executed, I get 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...  .py", line 123, in grade_scores
    count[4] += 1
NameError: name 'count' is not defined

Comment: @Jennga If you have copied my code directly from this post, you have to uncomment the part where I define the list count and all the other things.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print something in grid format then use tabulate package. It is easy and convinient . Here is sample code :

```
 from tabulate import tabulate
 table = [["spam",42],["eggs",451],["bacon",0]]
 headers = ["item", "qty"]
 print tabulate(table, headers, tablefmt="grid")
```

This prints :

```
+--------+-------+
| item   |   qty |
+========+=======+
| spam   |    42 |
+--------+-------+
| eggs   |   451 |
+--------+-------+
| bacon  |     0 |
+--------+-------+
```